# why the php array in this format

Tags: php

I have an array which is generated by a sql

```
array(1){
[13]=>{
["time"]=>
string(10) "1382927070"
["name"]=>
int(13)
}
```

Why the "name" is int(13) instead of int(2) "13"?

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an integer, and its value is `13`. It's not a string, and it's length isn't 2, so it doesn't output it in `string(2) "13"` format. This is simply how `vardump` tells you about the things you tell it to dump.

Comment: @megar Is it possible to change it from int to string by using mysql?

Comment: Why would you want to? It's an int. If you want to store it as a string, change the column type. Otherwise, you could coerce it, or simply convert it to a string in PHP, but **why**?

Comment: will it affect when i do array_merge if i keep it as int? as I need to get the value

Comment: Did you **try** whatever it is you're trying to do? Worry about it if it becomes a problem.

Comment: I am debugging, i just wonder if it still can the do the same procedure by passing a string and an integer. actually they are numbers